# jax-RS project deployed success but has 404 error when open URL with IE

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, wildfly

I wrote a JAX-RS test project. After I run it in eclipse with wildfly 11, I opened the URL with IE and receive a 404 error.
The code is like below:
Package name:   Test_rs_01.
HellowWorldResource.java

```
package org.jboss.jaxrs.rest;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {
    @GET
    @Path("helloworld")
    public String helloworld() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

RestApplication.java

```
package rest.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

}
```

I tried with this URL,http://localhost:8080/Test__rs_01/rest/helloworld/helloworld and 404 error happened. Can someone help? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

1. The URL you mentioned ("*I tried with this URL...*") contains two underscores (_) after "Test".
2. In general, `Test_rs_01` is the context path of your web application only as long as you don't (accidentally) change it, e.g.

   1. via `context.xml`
   2. `@ApplicationPath`, used with leading slash (`/`), also overrides the context path for the scope of the REST service
   3. if you have a `WEB-INF/web.xml` file, you should check any `<servlet-mapping>` there because that would override `@ApplicationPath`

Answer (score 0):

1. The query URL you mentioned `http://localhost:8080/[This will be deployed web context name]/rest/helloworld/helloworld`
2. By default web context name will your war file name.